# onnxruntime 1.17.0 warning about memcpy nodes for CUDA Execution Provider

Tags: onnxruntime

After onnxruntime update from version 1.14.0 to 1.17.0 I've got the warning:
[W:onnxruntime:, transformer_memcpy.cc:74 onnxruntime::MemcpyTransformer::ApplyImpl] 9 Memcpy nodes are added to the graph svm for CUDAExecutionProvider. It might have negative impact on performance (including unable to run CUDA graph). Set session_options.log_severity_level=1 to see the detail logs before this message.
The warning appears when I initialize onnxruntime session with model that I had converted previously from tensorflow to onnx with tf2onnx library.

My first assumption was that I need to convert my model with opset=20 as it's corresponding version for onnxruntime 1.17.0, but tf2onnx proposes to set opset version only up till 18.
Has someone encountered such kind of warning? Could you explain the reason and how it can be fixed?